# How does one go about to achieve this "broken up" effect?

Tags: modeling, displacement

Was wondering how to achieve this "broken up" effect on models? I have tried to figure it out with the displace modifier but couldn't get very far.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you please use a descriptive title that reflects the content of the question?

Comment: Look for the "cell fracture" add on

Comment: The effect actually is very much there , one called Cell Fracture Go to Edit > Preferences >Addons and search **Cell Fracture** and enable it  and you might find that in the properties

Comment: Instead of adding "solved" to the title, please write a proper answer in the answers section, and mark it as accepted,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under "Edit" in the upper left corner, go to preferences. Then go to add-ons and search for "cell fracture." Once you enable this add-on, the options to apply this effect will be under "Object" in the "Quick Effects" section.